# Nodejs - Transfer data between two server and client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, koa

I started to implement a HTTP ping health monitor as a private project with React and Node.js. I thought about making monitor with intervals that will send an axios request to server to receive all the urls and will return the results to server which will be shown later on in the client side.

I don't wanna use REST API to transfer data between the monitor and the server and to show it lively in the client side.

```
MONITOR <--> SERVER <--> CLIENT
```

What should I use instead of REST API in order to communicate between the monitor and the server? I know socket.io is fine to communicate between the client and the server but it is not so good for scaling.

What will be good and fast to transfer data for this specific project and not so hard to implement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Server Sent Events in NodeJS, that is a way of receiving events from the server. Then you can use EventSource to open a connection to the server to begin receiving events from it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Take a look at this tutorial from DigitalOcean:

[How To Use Server-Sent Events in Node.js to Build a Realtime App](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app#:%7E:text=%20How%20To%20Use%20Server-Sent%20Events%20in%20Node.js,Frontend.%20In%20this%20part%20of%20our...%20More%20)

Also take a look at Socket.io:

https://socket.io/

Comment: I'm looking for transferring data between two different servers first of all. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In this case you can use gRPC:
https://grpc.io/

Comment: Does it have the option to ensure the connection between two sides?

Comment: It is Bi-directional streaming. Another option you have is websocket, that´s why i mentioned socket.io in the response.